# C compiler and C99 standard

Tags: c, c99

Which C compilers can compile C99 compliant source?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations

Comment: Pretty much all of the major ones apart from MSVC...

Comment: @Bart please make this an answer, and, Eminem, mark it please, before the question is closed as "too broad". ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't mess up `gcc` allow you to do so while using `-std=gnu99` or `-std=c99` option

Comment: Unless it has changed recently though, that isn't fully compliant - so may not be suitable if say you are developing in a MISRA environment